# Another Complex SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Revised Again:

```
SELECT x.Imaging, x.Indication FROM medicalimaging x 
 WHERE MCGID = '1036' 
and x.Indication not in (
select Indication FROM invoicefields a join invoices b on a.InvoiceNumber = b.InvoiceNumber WHERE a.PatientID = '10120003' and x.MCGID = b.StudyID and x.Imaging = a.TypeOfExam
)
Order By Imaging ASC, Indication ASC
```

Thank you all for your answers, I did some research and this is what I cam up with.

```
SELECT x.Imaging, x.Indication
FROM medicalimaging x
WHERE MCGID =  'McG 1032'
AND x.Indication NOT 
IN (

SELECT Indication
FROM invoicefields a
JOIN invoices b ON a.InvoiceNumber = b.InvoiceNumber
WHERE a.PatientID =  '10120003'
AND x.MCGID = b.StudyID
)
```

I am trying to figure out what already has been invoiced and exclude it from a list. These are my tables, some sample data, and the query results.

```
Medical Imaging ( These are the fields to be used in the list)
id | MCGID | Imaging | Indication 
1    1032     Xray       Visit 1
2    1032     Xray       Visit 2
3    1032     Xray       Visit 3
4    1032     CT         Emergency
5    1045     Xray       Initial

invoice ( Generic Invoice Data)
InvoiceNumber | StudyID |     TypeInvoice       | void | 
     1            1032        Medical Imaging        0 
     2            1045        Medical Imaging        0
     3            1032        Medical Imaging        1
     4            1032        Medical Imaging        0 

Invoicefields ( The Rows of charges in the Invoice ) 
InvoiceNumber     |    PatientID   |    TypeofExam   | Indication 
1                   PT25        Xray            Visit 1   
1                   PT30        Xray            Visit 1   
2                   PT36        Xray            Initial
2                   PT25        Xray            Initial
4                   PT25        Xray            Visit 2   
4                   PT30        Xray            Visit 2   
4                   PT25        Xray            Visit 3   

After Query Results


Ex. 1 Provided  MCGID=1032  and PatientID=PT25.

Results:   CT , Emergency


Ex. 2 Provided  MCGID=1032  and PatientID=PT30.


Results:           Xray    ,    Visit 3         
                   CT       ,   Emergency
```

So, This is the generic structure. For reference, MCGID is the SAME as StudyID, and Type of Exam is the SAME as Imaging. Another thing to note is MCGID is unique, and PatientID is only unique to the MCGID. This means that the PatientID can be reused for another MCGID.  For the Query to run, I will provide it with PatientID, and MCGID. So my goal is to create a list of potential Imaging and Indications that are not listed in the invoicefields under TypeofExam and Indication. Also, it should also ignore the invoice number if void=1.

EDIT :

I understand basic sql functions, I understand how to pull data from multiple tables, I just dont get how to cross reference data from multiple tables. The issue is I have to cross reference data about 3 times. So this is where I am at now.

```
SELECT medicalimaging.Imaging,medicalimaging.Indication FROM medicalimaging WHERE MCGID='1032'
```

I am just not sure how to tell it to get the data from the other tables and compare it to the data I am about to pull.

Comment: We might be able to help you, but you'll need to show us your work to date. What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Can you please post your table data as text rather than an image? - highlight it then Ctl-k to format it as a code block.

Comment: Guess I am alone on this one.

Comment: In order to solve this, I think you need a link between the mgcid and the patient_id.  I can't see any way to link the invoices back to the imaging records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution is to use exist to find Imaging data having invoices and exclude them:

```
select *
 from MedicalImaging mi
 where mi.mcgid = 1032
   and not exists (select null
                     from Invoice i
                    inner join InvoiceFields f
                       on i.invoicenumber = f.invoicenumber
                    where i.studyid = mi.mcgid
                      and i.void = 0
                      and f.typeOfExam = mi.imaging
                      and f.Indication = mi.indication
                      and f.PatientID = 'PT30')
```

I had to be creative here. I've added `InvoiceFields.Indication = MedicalImaging.Indication` to be able to narrow down repeated exams. The reasoning behind this schema is unclear to me. Perhaps you have undisclosed tables concerning patients that would explain how you know which PatientID to supply for this query to work.

[Here is DEMO @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bdac/7). You might alter schema there to provide more informations, and post a link back.

Comment: +1 very concise (unlike my attempt!)

Comment: I will test this anyway, out of curiosity and rate it if it works. Thanks!^^

Answer (score 1):

This feels sloppy but it seems to work. SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76df8/49/2).

```
set @Patient = 'PT25';
set @MCGID = 1032;
select distinct
  @Patient PatientID,
  m.id,
  m.MCGID,
  m.Imaging,
  m.Indication
from 
  MedicalImaging m
  inner join 
  (
    select
      i.StudyID,
      f.PatientID,
      f.TypeOfExam,
      f.Indication
    from 
      invoice i
      inner join InvoiceFields f 
        on i.InvoiceNumber = f.InvoiceNumber
    where 
      f.PatientID = @Patient
      and i.StudyID = @MCGID
  ) p
  on m.MCGID = p.StudyID
where not exists
  (
    select
      i.StudyID,
      f.PatientID,
      f.TypeOfExam,
      f.Indication
    from 
      invoice i
      inner join InvoiceFields f 
        on i.InvoiceNumber = f.InvoiceNumber
    where 
      f.PatientID = @Patient
      and i.StudyID = @MCGID
      and f.TypeOFExam = m.Imaging
      and f.Indication = m.Indication
  )
;
```